# Handling IncompleteRead,URLError

Tags: python, error-handling, urllib2, httplib

it's a piece of web mining script.

```
def printer(q,missing):
    while 1:
        tmpurl=q.get()
        try:
            image=urllib2.urlopen(tmpurl).read()
        except httplib.HTTPException:
            missing.put(tmpurl)
            continue
        wf=open(tmpurl[-35:]+".jpg","wb")
        wf.write(image)
        wf.close()
```

`q` is a `Queue()` composed of Urls and `missing is an empty queue to gather error-raising-urls

it runs in parallel by 10 threads.

and everytime I run this, I got this.

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 351, in read
    data = self._sock.recv(rbufsize)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 541, in read
    return self._read_chunked(amt)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 592, in _read_chunked
    value.append(self._safe_read(amt))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 649, in _safe_read
    raise IncompleteRead(''.join(s), amt)
IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(5274 bytes read, 2918 more expected)
```

but I do use the `except`...
I tried something else like

```
httplib.IncompleteRead
urllib2.URLError
```

even,

```
image=urllib2.urlopen(tmpurl,timeout=999999).read()
```

but none of this is working..

how can I catch the `IncompleteRead` and `URLError`?

Comment: Bit late, but first hit on google. Sooo, http://stackoverflow.com/a/14206036/1444854 should solve your problems. By the way, generally if you want to catch multiple exceptions, put them in a tuple: except (httplib.IncompleteRead, urllib2.URLError)

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct answer to this question depends on what you consider an "error-raising URL".

## Methods of catching multiple exceptions

If you think any URL which raises an exception should be added to the `missing` queue then you can do:

```
try:
    image=urllib2.urlopen(tmpurl).read()
except (httplib.HTTPException, httplib.IncompleteRead, urllib2.URLError):
    missing.put(tmpurl)
    continue
```

This will catch any of those three exceptions and add that url to the `missing` queue. More simply you could do:

```
try:
    image=urllib2.urlopen(tmpurl).read()
except:
    missing.put(tmpurl)
    continue
```

To catch *any* exception but this is not considered Pythonic and could hide other possible errors in your code.

If by "error-raising URL" you mean any URL that raises an `httplib.HTTPException` error but you'd still like to keep processing if the other errors are received then you can do:

```
try:
    image=urllib2.urlopen(tmpurl).read()
except httplib.HTTPException:
    missing.put(tmpurl)
    continue
except (httplib.IncompleteRead, urllib2.URLError):
    continue
```

This will only add the URL to the `missing` queue if it raises an `httplib.HTTPException` but will otherwise catch `httplib.IncompleteRead` and `urllib.URLError` and keep your script from crashing.

## Iterating over a Queue

As an aside, `while 1` loops are always a bit concerning to me. You should be able to loop through the Queue contents using the following pattern, though you're free to continue doing it your way:

```
for tmpurl in iter(q, "STOP"):
    # rest of your code goes here
    pass
```

## Safely working with files

As another aside, unless it's absolutely necessary to do otherwise, you should use [context managers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) to open and modify files. So your three file-operation lines would become:

```
with open(tmpurl[-35:]+".jpg","wb") as wf:
    wf.write()
```

The context manager takes care of closing the file, and will do so even if an exception occurs while writing to the file.