# Boto S3 throws httplib.IncompleteRead occasionally

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I have several daemons that read many files from Amazon S3 using boto. Once every couple of days, I'm running into a situation where an httplib.IncompleteRead is thrown out from deep inside boto. If I try and retry the request, it immediately fails with another IncompleteRead. Even if I call `bucket.connection.close()`, all further requests will still error out.

I feel like I might've stumbled across a bug in boto here, but nobody else seems to have hit it. Am I doing something wrong? All of the daemons are single-threaded, and I've tried setting `is_secure` both ways.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "<file_wrapper.py",> line 22, in next
    line = self.readline()
  File "<file_wrapper.py",> line 37, in readline
    data = self.fh.read(self.buffer_size)
  File "<virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/boto/s3/key.py",> line 378, in read
    self.close()
  File "<virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/boto/s3/key.py",> line 349, in close
    self.resp.read()
  File "<virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/boto/connection.py",> line 411, in read
    self._cached_response = httplib.HTTPResponse.read(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 529, in read
    s = self._safe_read(self.length)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 621, in _safe_read
    raise IncompleteRead(''.join(s), amt)
```

Environment:

- Amazon EC2
- Ubuntu 11.10
- Python 2.6.7
- Boto 2.12.0

Answer (score 5):

I've been struggling with this problem for a while, running long-running processes which read large amount of data from S3. I decided to post my solution here, for posterity.

First of all, I'm sure the hack pointed to by @Glenn works, but I chose not to use it because I consider it intrusive (hacking httplib) and unsafe (it blindly returns what it got, i.e. `return e.partial`, despite the fact it can be real-error-case).

Here is the solution I finally came up with, which seems to be working.

I'm using this general-purpose retrying function:

```
import time, logging, httplib, socket

def run_with_retries(func, num_retries, sleep = None, exception_types = Exception, on_retry = None):
    for i in range(num_retries):
        try:
            return func()  # call the function
        except exception_types, e:
            # failed on the known exception
            if i == num_retries - 1:
                raise  # this was the last attempt. reraise
            logging.warning(f'operation {func} failed with error {e}. will retry {num_retries-i-1} more times')
            if on_retry is not None:
                on_retry()
            if sleep is not None:
                time.sleep(sleep)
    assert 0  # should not reach this point
```

Now, when reading a file from S3, I'm using this function, which internally performs retries in case of `IncompleteRead` errors. Upon an error, before retrying, I call `key.close()`.

```
def read_s3_file(key):
    """
    Reads the entire contents of a file on S3.
    @param key: a boto.s3.key.Key instance
    """
    return run_with_retries(
        key.read, num_retries = 3, sleep = 0.5,
        exception_types = (httplib.IncompleteRead, socket.error),
        # close the connection before retrying
        on_retry = lambda: key.close()
    )
```

Comment: Throws `TypeError: close() got unexpected keyword argument 'fast'`. It doesn't look like close takes any kwargs: https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/response.html

Comment: @crypdick 6 years ago it did.  Feel free to edit and update my answer.

Answer (score 4):

It may well be a bug in boto, but the symptoms you describe are not unique to it. See

[IncompleteRead using httplib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149100/incompleteread-using-httplib)

https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/9554

Since httplib appears in your traceback, one solution is proposed here:

http://bobrochel.blogspot.in/2010/11/bad-servers-chunked-encoding-and.html?showComment=1358777800048

Disclaimer: I have no experience with boto. This is based on research only and posted since there have been no other responses.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I still haven't found a good solution to this, but you deserve the bounty more than anyone else ;)

Comment: Update: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/boto-users/YiPAOvxIrUY

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading a large amount of data from S3, you may have to chunk/multi-part your read/write.

There is a good example here on doing the multi-part (http://www.bogotobogo.com/DevOps/AWS/aws_S3_uploading_large_file.php)