# Frequent ChunkedEncodingError with Google App Engine / Requests

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-requests

I frequently have a `ChunkedEncodingError` when requesting servers using `Requests` (Python) and Google App Engine.

I looked at the answer from [IncompleteRead using httplib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14206036/330867) but the problem is that I don't believe my issue is related to the querying server : I often get this error with various endpoints I'm using, including Intercom and FullContact.

I would have suspected the issue was related to the server of one service if the issue was always raised from the same server (for example, FullContact), but it's not the case. I've also encounter this issue with other, non related, requests.

So I'm suspecting the problem is either my code or Google. But from my code "point of view", I don't know what would be wrong. Here's a snippet:

```
result = requests.post(
    "https://api.intercom.io/companies",
    json={'some': 'data', 'that': 'are', 'sent': 'ok'},
    headers={'Accept': 'application/json'},
    auth=("app_id", "app_key",)
)
```

As you can see, the request is quite standard, nothing fancy. It also fails with something as simple as:

```
r = requests.get(url, params=params, timeout=3)
```

Does anyone experiences those issues with Google App Engine? Is there something I can do to avoid that?

Comment: What version of requests are you using?

Comment: I'm using requests 2.9.1, why? (and Python 2.7)

Comment: Prior to 2.10.0, requests did not support GAE in its entirety. You should upgrade and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Ok I switched to the latest version and pushed the code. So far so good. I'll wait a few days and come back to you. You can already post your comment as an answer, I will already upvote it.

Answer (score 6):

There is a patch that (seems) to work on GAE.
The issue is located in the `iter_content` function of requests, that uses the subsequent urllib3 library.

The issue is that Google override this library for their own implementation, but with a few changes that yield a ChunkedEncodingError at the `Requests` level.

I tried [this patch](https://github.com/agfor/requests/commit/da863cc), and so far, so good. In details, you must replace the following line in your requests/models.py file :

```
for chunk in self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True):
    yield chunk
```

by :

```
if isinstance(self.raw._original_response._method, int):
    while True:
        chunk = self.raw.read(chunk_size, decode_content=True)
        if not chunk:
            break
        yield chunk
else:
    for chunk in self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True):
        yield chunk
```

And the problem will stop.

I [submitted an issue](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/3187) to talk about it on the Requests repository, and we'll see how this will evolve.