# http Protocol error when using streaming API within Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Any idea how this problem could be fixed?

```
in retweeted_status found hashtags:  1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 578, in _readinto_chunked
    n = self._safe_readinto(mvb)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 625, in _safe_readinto
    raise IncompleteRead(bytes(mvb[0:total_bytes]), len(b))
http.client.IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read, 512 more expected)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 331, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 413, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 448, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 478, in readinto
    return self._readinto_chunked(b)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 589, in _readinto_chunked
    raise IncompleteRead(bytes(b[0:total_bytes]))
http.client.IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mona_counthash_stream.py", line 248, in <module>
    streamer.filter(languages=["en"], track=unique_hashtags[:367])
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 450, in filter
    self._start(async)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 364, in _start
    self._run()
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 297, in _run
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 266, in _run
    self._read_loop(resp)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 316, in _read_loop
    line = buf.read_line().strip()
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 181, in read_line
    self._buffer += self._stream.read(self._chunk_size)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 430, in read
    raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 349, in _error_catcher
    raise ProtocolError('Connection broken: %r' % e, e)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)', IncompleteRead(0 bytes read))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149100/incompleteread-using-httplib/20645845#20645845 .

Comment: well, I am not making use of httplib directly, I am making use of Tweepy which makes use of Twitter API.